# Writing to a code mirror text box with selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, textbox, invisible, codemirror

I have a selenium script I've written in java that automates the input of some text into a text box for submission into a database. It was working fine until for some reason it broke one day, giving the error that the text box I was trying to write to was not visible. Several days later I've finality figured out that someone much higher up must have updated the text box to be using [code mirror](http://codemirror.net/1/contrib/xquery/index.html) which makes the text box invisible and creates some kind of java-script substitute thing.

I've been searching all day, and the only solutions I can find are disabling java-script within the selenium environment, causing the whole thing to default back to a normal text box, or somehow writing to the code mirror object with selenium. I haven't been able to find a way to do either, so would anybody here know a possible solution to my problem?

Cheers